# A question related to the boundedness of self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, physics, mathematical-physics

I am currently working on an the following exercise from Bryan C. Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians*:

> If $A$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator (on a Hilbert space), show that $U(t) := e^{iAt}$
> is continuous in the operator-norm topology.

I am kind of unsure as to how to proceed and any help/hint will be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\| (e^{itA}-e^{isA})\psi\|^2=\int_{\sigma(A)}|e^{itx}-e^{isx}|^2\mathrm d\mu_\psi(x)
$$
for $\mathrm d\mu_\psi$ the spectral measure corresponding to $\psi$. Then, by the mean value theorem
$$
\| (e^{itA}-e^{isA})\psi\|^2\leq |t-s|\int_{\sigma(A)}|x|\mathrm d\mu_\psi(x)\\
\leq |t-s|^2\max_{x\in \sigma(A)}|x|^2\mu_\psi(\sigma(A))
$$
so
$$
\|(e^{itA}-e^{isA})\|\leq |t-s|\|A\|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that
$$
\| e^{itA}-e^{isA}\| \to 0,
$$
as $|t-s|\to 0$, and where $\|\cdot \|$ denotes the operator norm. Recall that one way of defining this exponential is through the power series expansion, so that
$$
e^{itA}-e^{isA} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(itA)^k-(isA)^k}{k!}.
$$
Now write, for $k\geq 2$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(itA)^k-(isA)^k & =(t-s)iA[(itA)^{k-1}+(itA)^{k-2}(isA)+\ldots+(itA)(isA)^{k-2}+(isA)^{k-1}]\\
& = (t-s)(iA)^k[t^{k-1}+\ldots+s^{k-1}].
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Can you finish from here?